# assigning makefile variables from command line

Tags: command-line, makefile

when i want to pass variables to a make file from command line,I do something like this:

```
make Variable="bla bla"
```

but what if I want to add to a variable??

I tried this :

```
make Variable+="bla bla"
```

It generates compiler or linker error as if I have not added anything. any way around this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>Simply always use the `VAR += word` syntax in your `Makefile`, instead of `VAR = word`. Then on the command line,</strike>

```
 make VAR="bla bla"
```

makes `VAR` start with "bla bla" followed by the remaining words assigned in the `Makefile`.

This assumes your `make` supports `+=` syntax.

Another way is to use two different variables,
say, `VAR_CMDLINE` and `VAR_MAKE`, where in your `Makefile` you have

```
 VAR_MAKE = whatever default value $(VAR_CMDLINE)
 all:
         echo $(VAR_MAKE)
```

and run it as `make VAR_CMDLINE="my additions"`. This is as POSIXly portable as it gets.

Comment: lol that is brilliant. looks like my make does not support += though, It did not work.
how do i make sure if it supports or not ??

Comment: Then I suggest you install GNU make (aka gmake). It has all the features you could possible want, and then some.

Comment: Using `+=` won't work.  The assignment on the command line has a higher priority than the one in the makefile and will override it completely.  There are ways around it but it's not pleasant, and definitely not portable.  The second suggestion is the right one.

Comment: Thanks, I "deleted" that part.